# Freeware tool for slowing down a video and audio

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, video

I created an animation with the free version of Hitfilm Express and I would like to slow it down a little bit. Although generally this is possible with Hitfilm Express, the quality of the sound is extremely bad (when slowing down the audio the pitch is ridiculously low and when speeding up it is ridiculously high). So I would like to know whether there is a free tool in which I can just upload the video (with the corresponding audio) and specify a percentage for decreasing the speed of the video and the audio simultaneously such that the video and audio are still in sync and the sound still sounds realistic.

Comment: There is no tool, free or not. You cannot have the audio remain the same, the video change speed, and the music stay synced. It's logically impossible

Comment: @ZachSaucier: Why do you think it's not possible? I think it is possible using FFmpeg: https://superuser.com/a/1394709/648100 and https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

Comment: @ZachSaucier - sure it's possible. I just don't know of any video tool that does it. It's easy in an audio editor.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am aware that the audio will not sound 100% realistic. But for example when watching a video on Youtube and speeding or slowing it up or down, it still sounds good for me. The tool that I am using (Hitfilm Express) transforms the sound in a ridiculously way. So there are definitely methods of doing this because Youtube is also doing it in an acceptable way.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>This is not a graphics design question but you could consider Motion Graphics as Graphic design, so.</sub>

Separate the audio from the video, and edit it on Audacity.

Open your track. Effects > Change Tempo.

Turn on the High-quality Checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem when just editing the sound and the video separately is, that it will be quite difficult to sync them later. This is why I'd prefer a freeware solution, that can handle both video and sound because Audacity is only for sound.

Comment: Resyncing is no problem if one has in a multitrack video editor prepared in the beginning (=before the actual program) and in the end short clicks to the audio and easy to find marking frames of those clicks to the video. People must do it continuously when they record video and audio with unsynced separate recorders. It's well possible that minor stretching or squeezing is needed if there's a long continuous run.

Comment: @user287001: Thanks for your comment. Acutally I don't really understand why resyncing is not a problem. If I just adjust the audio with Audacity and adjust the video separatedly with Hitfilm, I assume it will be quite difficult to sync them. This is why I am looking for a tool that can handle both video and audio simultaneously. But the more I look for it, the more I get the impression, that such a freeware tool does not exist that offers good quality. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Resync = After importing the tuned audio item back to the video editor stretch the video or audio item so that the markings which you made BEFORE visiting in Audacity, fit.

Comment: @Rafael: I tried your suggested solution but to be totally honest, the audio quality sounds quite bad using Audacity. It does not sound natural any more altough I just decreased the speed by 5 percent